# Why does IIS generate asp.net pages so slowly?

Tags: asp.net, iis, optimization

When i run asp.net (forms) site using Visual Studio Web Dev Server the site works pretty fast (everything is optimized under profilers), firebug shows that page takes ~100ms to be generated. But when its deployed on vps under IIS the same page takes ~400ms.

Why does IIS generate page longer than mean VS Dev Server?

I mean exactly page generation, without loading, so it's not depend on slow network or whatever. I could suppose what the vps was slow, but it had 4BG RAM, 2 processors and ran only one asp.net site so nothing could waste the resources.

If VS Dev Server can generate page in ~100ms so i guess IIS should be able do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not IIS. It is your low quality VPS with limited shared resources. Try some better server or test on local IIS.

Comment: hm, thanx, i will try to setup IIS on local computer and test

Comment: btw, is there any tools for testing of vps quality ?

Comment: You don't need. Check the CPU, RAM and test upload/download speed. The term you are looking for is `benchmarking`.